# Automatically generated move constructor with not movable members

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I got in a situation which is quite interesting as the code I'm working on compiles even though I'm surprised it does so I would like to ask you for your take.

The situation is this. I have a class with deleted move and copy constructors, which has user-defined assignment operators:

```
struct A {
    A() { }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&& ) = delete;

    A& operator=(const A& ) { return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&& ) { return *this; }
};
```

And I have another class with `A` as the only member. In this class I defined the copy constructor but I kept the move constructor as default and defined the assignment operator through a call to the swap function:

```
class B{
public:
    A a;

    B()
    : a{}
    { }

    B(const B&)
    : a{}
    { }

    B(B&& other) = default;
};

int main() {
    B b1;
    B b2(std::move(b1)); // compiles??
}
```

Why does the default move constructor work, considering that it cannot simply call the move or copy constructor A? I am using gcc 4.8.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My original answer was wrong, so I'm starting over.

---

In [class.copy], we have:

> A defaulted copy/
>   move constructor for a class X is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>   — [...]
>   — a potentially constructed subobject type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because
>   overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a
>   function that is **deleted** or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
>   — [...]

That bullet point applies to `B(B&& other) = default;`, so that move constructor is defined as deleted. This would seem to break compilation with `std::move()`, but we also have (via resolution of [defect 1402](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402)):

> A defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted is **ignored by overload resolution** (13.3, 13.4). *[ Note:*
>   A deleted move constructor would otherwise interfere with initialization from an rvalue which can use the
>   copy constructor instead. *—end note ]*

Ignoring is the key. Thus, when we do:

```
B b1;
B b2(std::move(b1));
```

Even though the move constructor for `B` is deleted, this code is well-formed because the move constructor simply doesn't participate in overload resolution and the copy constructor is called instead. Thus, `B` is MoveConstructible - even if you cannot construct it via its move constructor.

Comment: I added a couple of couts in the copy and assignment and it seems to confirm your hypothesis that, unable to compile correctly the move constructor, it simply reverts to the copy. I'm not an expert of the subtleties of the standard but it looks like the default declaration behaves like SFINAE in a template

Comment: A defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted is ignored by overload resolution. See N4527 [class.copy]/p11; also [N3667](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3667.html)